# How to split a numpy array based on a column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of the form :

```
[[ 1. ,    2.,     3.,     1.,     3.,     3.,     4.   ],
 [ 1.3,    2.3,    3.3,    3.,     3.3,    3.3,    4.3  ],
 [ 1.2,    2.2,    3.2,    2.,     3.2,    3.2,    4.2  ],
 [ 1.1,    2.1,    1.,     1.,     3.,     3.,     4.   ],
 [ 1.3,    2.3,    3.5,    3.,     3.3,    3.3,    4.3  ],
 [ 1.2,    2.7,    3.2,    2.,     3.2,    3.2,    4.2  ],
 [ 1.3,    2.2,    1.,     1.,     3.,     3.,     4.   ],
 [ 1.3,    2.3,    3.6,    3.,     3.3,    3.3,    4.3  ],
 [ 1.2,    2.8,    3.2,    2.,     3.2,    3.2,    4.2  ],
 [ 1.4,    2.3,    1.,     1.,     3.,     3.,     4.   ],
 [ 1.3,    2.3,    3.7,    3.,     3.3,    3.3,    4.3  ],
 [ 1.2,    2.9,    3.2,    2.,     3.2,    3.2,    4.2  ],
 [ 1.5,    2.1,    1.,     1.,     3.,     3.,     4.   ],
 [ 1.89,   2.3,    3.5,    3.,     3.3,    3.3,    4.3  ],
 [ 1.2,    2.7,    3.2,    2.,     3.2,    3.231,  4.2  ],
 [ 1.9,    2.2,    1.,     1.,     3.,     3.,     4.   ],
 [ 1.3,    2.22,   3.6,    3.,     3.3,    3.3,    4.3  ],
 [ 1.2,    2.8,    3.2,    2.,     3.66,   3.2,    4.2  ],
 [ 1.89,   2.3,    1.,     1.,     3.,     3.,     4.   ],
 [ 1.3,    2.99,   3.7,    3.,     3.3,    3.3,    4.3  ],
 [ 1.2,    2.9,    3.2,    2.,     3.34,   3.2,    4.2  ]]
```

I want to split this array into a number of subarrays based on the *fourth* column. I.e. I want one subarray whose fourth column is equal to 1, another one where the fourth column is equal to 2, etc. **I do not know in advance what all possible values are there in fourth column.**

For instance, the subarray corresponding to fourth column being 1 is :

```
[[ 1.     2.     3.     1.     3.     3.     4.   ],
 [ 1.1    2.1    1.     1.     3.     3.     4.   ],
 [ 1.3    2.2    1.     1.     3.     3.     4.   ],
 [ 1.4    2.3    1.     1.     3.     3.     4.   ],
 [ 1.5    2.1    1.     1.     3.     3.     4.   ],
 [ 1.9    2.2    1.     1.     3.     3.     4.   ],
 [ 1.89   2.3    1.     1.     3.     3.     4.   ]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a list of arrays:

```
y = [x[x[:,3]==k] for k in np.unique(x[:,3])]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `O(NlogN)` time using `numpy.argsort`, `numpy.array_split`, `numpy.diff` and `numpy.where`:

```
>>> indices = np.argsort(arr[:, 3])
>>> arr_temp = arr[indices]
>>> np.array_split(arr_temp, np.where(np.diff(arr_temp[:,3])!=0)[0]+1)
[array([[ 1.  ,  2.  ,  3.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 1.89,  2.3 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 1.1 ,  2.1 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 1.9 ,  2.2 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 1.3 ,  2.2 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 1.5 ,  2.1 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 1.4 ,  2.3 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  3.  ,  3.  ,  4.  ]]), array([[ 1.2  ,  2.8  ,  3.2  ,  2.   ,  3.66 ,  3.2  ,  4.2  ],
       [ 1.2  ,  2.7  ,  3.2  ,  2.   ,  3.2  ,  3.231,  4.2  ],
       [ 1.2  ,  2.9  ,  3.2  ,  2.   ,  3.2  ,  3.2  ,  4.2  ],
       [ 1.2  ,  2.9  ,  3.2  ,  2.   ,  3.34 ,  3.2  ,  4.2  ],
       [ 1.2  ,  2.8  ,  3.2  ,  2.   ,  3.2  ,  3.2  ,  4.2  ],
       [ 1.2  ,  2.7  ,  3.2  ,  2.   ,  3.2  ,  3.2  ,  4.2  ],
       [ 1.2  ,  2.2  ,  3.2  ,  2.   ,  3.2  ,  3.2  ,  4.2  ]]), array([[ 1.3 ,  2.3 ,  3.6 ,  3.  ,  3.3 ,  3.3 ,  4.3 ],
       [ 1.89,  2.3 ,  3.5 ,  3.  ,  3.3 ,  3.3 ,  4.3 ],
       [ 1.3 ,  2.3 ,  3.5 ,  3.  ,  3.3 ,  3.3 ,  4.3 ],
       [ 1.3 ,  2.22,  3.6 ,  3.  ,  3.3 ,  3.3 ,  4.3 ],
       [ 1.3 ,  2.3 ,  3.3 ,  3.  ,  3.3 ,  3.3 ,  4.3 ],
       [ 1.3 ,  2.99,  3.7 ,  3.  ,  3.3 ,  3.3 ,  4.3 ],
       [ 1.3 ,  2.3 ,  3.7 ,  3.  ,  3.3 ,  3.3 ,  4.3 ]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

I turned @ashwini-chaudhary 's idea in a way that returns the indices of interest for later iteration. So I figured I would share it:

```py
def split_idx_by_dim(dim_array):
    """Returns a sequence of arrays of indices of elements sharing the same value in dim_array"""
    idx = np.argsort(dim_array)
    sorted_cl_ids = dim_array[idx]
    split_idx = np.array_split(idx, np.where(np.diff(sorted_cl_ids) != 0)[0] + 1)
    return split_idx
```

Answer (score -2):

Look at the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy.hsplit) for splitting an array into multiple sub-arrays.

> numpy.hsplit(ary, indices_or_sections)
>
> Split an array into multiple sub-arrays horizontally (column-wise).

So say you have a 4x4 array A:

```
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
   [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
   [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
   [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.]])

split = numpy.hsplit(A,4) = 

[array([[  0.],
   [  4.],
   [  8.],
   [ 12.]]), array([[  1.],
   [  5.],
   [  9.],
   [ 13.]]), array([[  2.],
   [  6.],
   [ 10.],
   [ 14.]]), array([[  3.],
   [  7.],
   [ 11.],
   [ 15.]])]
```

Comment: sorry, wrong function. this one should be easy to use.