# Split numpy array by value of the first column

Tags: python, numpy, split

I have the following NumPy array

```
[[  0 935]
 [  0 331]
 [  0 322]
 [  1 339]
 [  1 773]
 [  2 124]
 [  2 340]
 [  3 810]
 [  5 936]
 [  5 252]]
```

and would like to separate it into

```
[[  0 935]
 [  0 331]
 [  0 322]]

[[  1 339]
 [  1 773]]

[[  2 124]
 [  2 340]]

[[  3 810]]

[[  5 936]
 [  5 252]]
```

Are there any fast solutions to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space between `0 935` or are they a list of length 2

Comment: @AdityaMishra that is how numpy arrays print out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all equal numbers located in one place you can do:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[  0, 935],
 [  0, 331],
 [  0, 322],
 [  1, 339],
 [  1, 773],
 [  2, 124],
 [  2, 340],
 [  3, 810],
 [  5, 936],
 [  5, 252],])
print(np.array_split(a, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a[:, 0])) + 1))
# [array([[  0, 935],
#        [  0, 331],
#        [  0, 322]]), array([[  1, 339],
#        [  1, 773]]), array([[  2, 124],
#        [  2, 340]]), array([[  3, 810]]), array([[  5, 936],
#        [  5, 252]])]
```

otherwise you can first sort array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[  0, 935],
 [  5, 936],
 [  2, 124],
 [  2, 340],
 [  5, 252],])
a.sort(axis=0)
print(*np.array_split(a, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a[:, 0])) + 1), sep="\n")
# [[  0 124]]
# [[  2 252]
#  [  2 340]]
# [[  5 935]
#  [  5 936]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
# Note: k is your array
import numpy as np
k = np.array([[  0, 935],[  0, 331],[  0, 322],
             [ 1, 339],[  1, 773],[  2, 124],
             [  2, 340],[  3, 810],[  5, 936],
             [  5, 252]])

# sort  indices
indices = np.argsort(k[:, 0])

# use indices to get sorted array
arr_temp = k[indices]

# retrieve your answer
net = np.array_split(arr_temp, 
      np.where(np.diff(arr_temp[:,0])!=0)[0]+1)
net[0]
```

This solution was inspired from [How to split a numpy array based on a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155597/how-to-split-a-numpy-array-based-on-a-column)