# Split Numpy array by column value, while keeping track of row indexs

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

Say I have a numpy array:

```
Y.shape = (n, 3)
```

where n is the amount of rows in the numpy array.

I split Y based on the values of the second column by following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155597/how-to-split-a-numpy-array-based-on-a-column):

```
distances = [Y[Y[:, 1] == k] for k in np.unique(Y[:, 1])]
```

Distances is now a list of numpy arrays of N length, where N is the number of possible values in the second column. I create a loop to split each array in **distances**, repeating the above step, however splitting by the last column this time like so:

```
for idx, dist in enumerate(distances):    
  conditions = [dist[dist[:, 2] == k] for k in np.unique(dist[:, 2])]
  # Save conditions list and do something with it
```

How in numpy can I get the row indexes of the oringal Y numpy array that correspond to each numpy array in **conditions**?

Comment: For me, the snippet you posted to find `conditions` results in losing any arrays in `distances` that were 1 row. E.g. if I start with `Y = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [7,8,9], [10,8,3], [11,3,2]])`, the step to find `distances` keeps all rows, but the final step leaves me with `conditions = [array([[10,  8,  3]]), array([[7, 8, 9]])]` while discarding all other rows. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Yes this is correct! As I will iterate through each numpy array in the distances list.

Comment: I meant that even with the `enumerate` statement, rows are discarded because `conditions` is being overwritten during every iteration of the loop. The whole `for idx, dist in enumerate(distances)` section only keeps rows from my `Y` array where 2+ rows have the same value in the middle column.

Comment: Updated the question, I am saving the conditions list after each iteration of the loop, what I am looking for is the matching original indexes of Y

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're storing `conditions` in another list (I used `all_conditions` in my code), then this is a potential start-to-finish solution:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

# The code you posted
distances = [Y[Y[:, 1] == k] for k in np.unique(Y[:, 1])]

# conditions are stored in this list
all_conditions = []
for idx, dist in enumerate(distances):
    conditions = [dist[dist[:, 2] == k] for k in np.unique(dist[:, 2])]
    all_conditions.append(conditions)

# This step flattens all_conditions so there are no nested lists.
all_conditions = reduce(operator.concat, list(all_conditions))

# For some reason, each row of 3 is within an extra bracket,
# so need to index the 0th element of each element in all_conditions.
# There is probably a more efficient way to extract them than a for loop,
# but this is the best I can come up with.

indices = np.zeros((len(all_conditions),3), dtype=int)
for i in range(len(all_conditions)):
    indices[i] = all_conditions[i][0]

# Select the values from X using the indices array as the indices.
selected = X[tuple(indices.T)]
```

Let me know if there's anything that needs clarification.